# Retrieval of lost Hyperledger wallet user details

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

We use MongoDB as a wallet to store wallet identities, but we lost (deleted) data from MongoDB collection.  Now we have to retrieve those identities.  What functionality is available to retrieve those identities?

Network components:

- Hyperledger Fabric version 2.3
- Fabric-CA version: latest

Network configuration:

- 3 organization setup with Couch DB as state database
- 5 orderer setup with RAFT consensus

The Hyperledger code is running in a Kubernetes cluster with NFS server.

Your pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user private keys contained in the wallet are, well... private. They don't exist anywhere else so unless you can recover the deleted MongoDB data, they are gone. You could re-enrol the lost user identities with the CA to issue new certificates for those users based on new private keys.

Comment: Hi @bestbeforetoday, how to re-enroll the lost users with the CA?  What command or code?  Or do we need to re-deploy the blockchain network?  Please elaborate.  Thanks!

Comment: See details in the documentation: https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployguide/use_CA.html. If you are using a commercial deployment environment, or a management tool such as https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/fabric-operations-console, they may have their own process.